# How to send auto login email using Email Auto Login drupal module?

Tags: 7, emails, users

I have enabled [Email Auto login](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_auto_login) Module on drupal 7. How can I send an auto login email using the above module.
 I have enabled the module and then saved the settings from the link
http://www.example.com/admin/config/system/email_auto_login.
 I have even checked the README file but could not find a way to send a auto login email using token
How can I send the auto login email using this module?

Answer (score 1):

First of all to send out an email automatically you will need a triggering event – and probably also some condition, under which the action of 'sending' should be fired. Otherwise drupal will not know when to send out an email – and to whom.

I suppose you have a look at the Rules Module (https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). It might first look quite complex, but basically it consists of these three main elements you have to configure to add a new Rule to your webpage: Event, Condition and Action. With that you can automate almost everything, especially sending reminder-emails etc. – and most probably you can also trigger Email Auto login.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply now checking your answer . I am well versed with rules but i could not find a action specific to email auto login

Comment: or is it that if a send a system mail I will get a link with token which will automatically log me in??

Comment: I have actually not used the module myself, but I suppose it works like a 'layer' for any email your drupal installation sends, since on the project page it says "When Drupal sends an email to a registered user, this module changes the email so that the user is logged in automatically when they click any of the links in the email which points to the Drupal site". Have you actually tried it out yet?

Comment: no not yet, i will try to send a system and see if it works

Comment: I tried sending a system mail when user logs in with [site:url] as the token but did not recieve any token along with link